# Python/Matplotlib sub-plots - stacked bar plots - set fixed color for categories

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colors, subplot

I would like to create sub-plots of stacked bar plots from pandas df (using df.pivot_table) and keep the category color consistent (i.e., fixed) for the sub-plots.

The issue is that not every index value in the pivot table ('domain' in the sample df) has the same number of categories - so matplotlib restarts the coloring of the categories in each sub-plot - resulting in same colors being used for two different categories.

Here's the dummy code for illustration:

df:

```
    main domain category  val
0   cat1      a    apple    1
1   cat1      a   orange    1
2   cat1      a  broccli    1
3   cat1      b    apple    1
4   cat1      b   orange    1
5   cat1      a     plum    1
6   cat1      c    apple    1
7   cat2      b   orange    1
8   cat2      b   orange    1
9   cat2      b    apple    1
10  cat2      b   orange    1
11  cat2      c     plum    1
12  cat2      c    apple    1
13  cat2      b   orange    1
14  cat2      b   orange    1
```

Code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
sub_plot_grid = (4, 10)
sub_plot_col_size = 5
sub_plot_row_size = 3

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid(sub_plot_grid, (0, 0), colspan=sub_plot_col_size, rowspan=sub_plot_row_size)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid(sub_plot_grid, (0, 5), colspan=sub_plot_col_size, rowspan=sub_plot_row_size, sharey=ax1, sharex=ax1)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', length=0)
list_of_ax = [ax1, ax2]

sub_df_1 = df[df['main'] == 'cat1']
sub_df_2 = df[df['main'] == 'cat2']
list_of_df = [sub_df_1, sub_df_2]

for ax, df in zip(list_of_ax, list_of_df):
    df1 = df.pivot_table(index='domain', columns='category', values='val', aggfunc='sum', dropna=False,  margins=True).sort_values(by='All', ascending=False).drop('All').drop('All', axis=1)
    df1.drop(df1.loc[df1.sum(axis=1) == 0].index, inplace=True)
    df1.drop(columns=df1.columns[df1.sum() == 0], inplace=True)
    df1.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, alpha=0.7, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

The plot is:

[image]

The problem is visible in the 'orange' and 'plum' categories: in the first subplot - the color for 'orange' category is green in the second subplot the color is orange. The 'plum' category color in first sub-plot is red, and the in the second it is green.

I need the colors for each category to remain the same for all sub-plots.

I have searched for solutions for a while now and tried a few different things, including trying to manually pass a list of colors or use colormaps, but the problem of matplotlib restarting colors with each sub-plot remains.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the docs for the `color` argument for [bar charts with `pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html).  Specifically, the part about passing a `dict`:

> A dict of the form {column namecolor}, so that each column will be
> colored accordingly. For example, if your columns are called a and b, then passing {‘a’: ‘green’, ‘b’: ‘red’} will color bars for column a in green and bars for column b in red.

So if you define:

```
colors = {'apple':'red', 'orange':'orange', 'plum':'purple', 'broccli':'green'}
```

And then plot with:

```
df1.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, alpha=0.7, ax=ax, color=colors)
```

You get the following:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I had tried this already for my actual code - but when I pass a color dictionary like this - the subplot get rid of the y-axis labels and replace them with number (0 to n) and stop the 'sharey'.between the sub-plots. I can't figure out why that is happening - the plot code is the same as I shared in the example (albeit part for functions, etc.)

Comment: @Jerry hmm, I'm not sure how those issues would stem from adding this parameter.  I at least haven't seen it before.  You could try to explicitly set the `yticks` I suppose?  I guess best would be if you can recreate those issues using this approach and update your example.

Comment: I have no idea why but after a good night's sleep and a computer restart, passing the color dictionary works as it is supposed to - without messing up the y-ticks, etc. I will accept this answer, though I have no idea why it wasn't working to begin with. I am going to chalk this up to the gremlins and move on with my life. Thanks, Tom.

Comment: @Jerry Sounds like typical gremlins - glad it's working!